# printing the contents of an string array

Tags: x86

I am wanting to print the contents of a string array,str_array, and  whose  length is 13 including a carriage return and line feed since the strings are being read in from a file.

```
lea esi,str_array
input text, 13;input is a predefined macro
atoi text; is a predefined macro returning into ax
mov [esi],ax
```

Comment: what OS?  Most OSes have some kind of equivalent to the POSIX `write`  system call that takes a buffer+length.  (On POSIX OSes like Linux, the system call is called `write`.)

Comment: i windows I ended up copying the string over byte by byte thanks for the concern !